# Unable to clone project from remote repository

Tags: git, ssh, gerrit

I have generated ssh key by gitbash and add key on gerrit. After then when i am trying to clone the project then i got following..
///
Unable to negotiate with 10.136.96.136 port 29418: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed the documentation "[Set Up SSH Keys in Gerrit](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/Tutorial#Set_Up_SSH_Keys_in_Gerrit)", you should be able to [test your connection](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-upload.html#test_ssh) (before attempting any clone)

You should see:

```sh
 $ ssh -p 29418 sshusername@hostname

    ****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****

    Hi John Doe, you have successfully connected over SSH.

    Unfortunately, interactive shells are disabled.
    To clone a hosted Git repository, use:

    git clone ssh://sshusername@hostname:29418/REPOSITORY_NAME.git

  Connection to hostname closed.
```

So make sure ssh daemon is running on your Gerrit server, and listening to port 29418.
Make sure the `~gerrituser/.ssh/authorized_keys` is updated with the public key.

Finally, check if you have to [enable some legacy options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340853/7490).
For instance, test with:

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 p 29418 sshusername@hostname
```

(replace `gerrituser` or `sshusername` by the correct remote Gerrit user account)
(and replace `hostname` by the remote Gerrit server hostname)